# Checksum of ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to calculate the checksum of an iOS ipa file, to check if an iOS app is tampered with? Is it even possible to achieve this? Even if one is able to calculate the checksum before app upload, will the checksum change once the app gets released to app store?

Comment: IPAs (or rather, their contents) are already cryptographically signed using you distribution certificate. What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: +Gereon... how do expect to verify that checksum?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this with `codesign --verify`. Never tried, to be honest, because Apple already does this check as part of the uploading process.

Comment: +Gereon to be honest its a requirement from a client, if someone recomplies the ipa and sends a request to the server then maybe we can check the integrity of the app by comparing the checksum sent from the app with the checksum at server. I know if a hacker is able to recompile the app then he can send the checksum as well, but there are some clients who don't understand these things. just wanted to know if this is possible.

Comment: Hello GMAN, im looking into this interesting topic as well. Do you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can absolutely do this. I have done this in multiple projects, you cannot calculate the checksum of the IPA during the runtime but you can check for files in the IPA.

After your build the IPA, you can unpack the IPA and calculate the checksum of a particulate file inside the IPA and store it somewhere, maybe in your back end.

```
openssl dgst -sha512 somecorefile.something
```

then during runtime check the digest of the file to see if it has been tampered with.

Note: AppStore processing will change the IPA but not your core asset files or bundle files, so you can keep them as the point of truth and validate them during runtime.

For checking the checksum during runtime you can use [this](https://github.com/rnine/Checksum) or implement something yourself.

Comment: i want the integrity check to be done for the entire app, not just a particular file.

Comment: Also correct me if i am wrong, checking the digest of the file and sending it across to the server defeats the purpose of checking the integrity, the hacker can always change the outcome of this right? or is my understanding of this is wrong?

Comment: See sending this to the server is one of the ideas, you can do it locally too by injecting the checksum of a file during build time into the bundle. Many 3rd party security SDKs do this.

Comment: Hello @Satheesh, I think your idea is kind of betting? How do you decide which file do you perform checksum comparison? How many files do you do it within an app? Also, it could be that the hacker has tampered file A, but you checked on file B. hmm

Comment: @TommyLeong Maybe one of our core files or a random file every time at build and inject the file details to be checked during run time while building the IPA. Security tools do it one of the ways sometimes they do comparison of all the assets and resources, sometimes the executable to check if it was hooked/modified.